# How to make sure that php files are actually saved with utf-8 encoding?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, netbeans-8

I'm running into an annoying php utf8 netbeans encoding problem. I spent all night yesterday searching Google and also StackOverflow for solutions. I tried many things and it seems I can't get it to work. I know i'm doing something wrong...

I have a php project that needs to print french caracters like `é è ç à` but instead of the letter it outputs `�`

I added this to my file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <?php 
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    ?>
<head>
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
```

Some users suggested to modify `neatbeans.conf`by adding `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` on this line `netbeans_default_options`

Still the problem remains...

I right clicked on the project -> properties -> sources and my encoding is set to `windows-1252` I tried to change it to UTF-8 but it gives me this warning : `Changing to UTF-8 may cause some files to be unreadable. Would you like to continue>`

I clicked yes but the problem remains...

So how can I make sure my file is encoded in UTF-8? Easy way please.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done to resolve this kind of issue is using:

```
iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $value);
```

Comment: Can you please provide with full string of code? Not sure to understand. Do you mean in the header like this `<?php 
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $value);
    ?>` ?

Comment: Ah yes. The problem lies with the configuration either the php.ini or the config. This idea is per value level, where you don't have to configure the configuration of those two and will force the encoding on the source code. Even I have trouble with this kind of character encoding and couldn't find the best way to do it.

Comment: Hm. Looks like the issue isn't solved with this solution. Do you know how to convert/save the files to UTF8 using Notepad++?